# Compare table to itself and update one value based on another - bulk

Tags: sql

The following select provides a list of 8524 values. Half are duplicates of the other half, with different dates. I need to terminate the older values based on the new DateEffective

```
SELECT PRID, COUNT(SiteID) AS SiteID_Count FROM PRL
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN DateEffective AND DateTerminated 
and SiteGID in (190,191,192,193,30,31,32,33)
GROUP BY PRID
HAVING COUNT(SiteID)=2
ORDER BY PRID
```

Below table shows the current and expected result:

```
select * from PRL where SiteGID in (30,31,32,33) and PRID = 1339
UNION
select * from PRL where SiteGID in (190,191,192,193) and PRID = 1339
```

table:

```
| PRLID      | PRID   | SiteGID      | SiteID  | DateEffective  | DateTerminated
| 895        | 1339   | 30           | 4353    | 2010-04-10     | 9999-12-31    
| 966598     | 1339   | 191          | 4353    | 2021-02-19     | 9999-12-31    
      
| PRLID      | PRID   | SiteGID      | SiteID  | DateEffective  | DateTerminated
| 895        | 1339   | 30           | 4353    | 2010-04-10     | **2021-02-18**    
| 966598     | 1339   | 191          | 4353    | 2021-02-19     | 9999-12-31
```

I want to link two tmp tables together, possibly using row_number and partitions? I'm really not sure - any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to change the underlying date or just build a select that alters the data temporarily?

Comment: Alter the underlying data - or at least put it into a tmp table I can use the update the real one..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description,

1. PRLID is the primary key of table `PRL`
2. Grouping is based on (`PRID`, `SiteID`)
3. `DateTerminated` needs to be updated with following `DateEffective` - 1 day if applicable.

```
with cte as (
select prlid,
       date_sub(lead(date_effective,1) over (partition by prid, site_id order by date_effective), interval 1 day) as new_date_terminated
  from prl)
  update prl as p
    inner join cte c
   using (prlid)
     set p.date_terminated = c.new_date_terminated
   where c.new_date_terminated is not null
     and p.date_terminated <> c.new_date_terminated;
```

Outcome:

```
prlid |prid|site_gid|site_id|date_effective|date_terminated|
------+----+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+
   895|1339|      30|   4353|    2010-04-10|     2021-02-18|
966598|1339|     191|   4353|    2021-02-19|     9999-12-31|
```

Comment: Looks like my SSMS isn't compatible with date_sub

Comment: @Badja For SQL server, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Please add sql-server tag to your question.